# Redirect file writes from an application

Tags: linux, command-line, shell

Under Raspbian, I'm using a closed-source application that writes some temporary files to disk, does a bit of work, and then quickly destroys them. I'd like to inspect those intermediate products, so I am hoping there's a way to redirect the writes or otherwise make the temporary files persistent.

So far, I've used opensnoop to confirm the existence and location of the temporary files.

Any suggestions? I have the option of doing this on OSX, if that's easier. TIA.

Comment: One possible hack might be be to mount the path to a SMB share and use sambas "recycle:" options to keep a copy of all deleted files.  (https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages/vfs_recycle.8.html)

Comment: Another possibility may be to set the sticky bit on the directory and change the owner.  (See http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7727)

Comment: The cleanest thing is to use *inotifywait* and the creation of a hard link. They can be combined into a simple script.

Comment: inotifywait turns out to be the winner, as I can use it to just copy the file immediately once it's been closed for writing.

Answer (score 1):

You can hook into write() and all similar functions. Using LD_PRELOAD, you can redirect libc functions, and write data as you please, then pass the application on to the real write() function - for example. I assume your program is dynamically linked. See https://rafalcieslak.wordpress.com/2013/04/02/dynamic-linker-tricks-using-ld_preload-to-cheat-inject-features-and-investigate-programs/ .

Edit: 
You can also start a (fast) bash loop in the temp. directory, and set the user immutable flag on the files of interest at short intervals.
`cd /tmp ; while true ; do chflags uchg foo* ; sleep 0.01 ; done`
This may disrupt your app, or it may pass over its internal deletion errors. To clear the flags, use `nouchg`.

Comment: It is an answer. OP has not specified if his binary is static. OP, you can use `file binaryFile` to discover this.

Comment: Far out. I'll use the sticky bit to prevent the intermediate files from being destroyed but I definitely learned something new from your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to pause the program temporarily until you're finished inspecting the temporary files. Note though, that the program might fail to resume correctly afterwards, so if it opens any important user files, be sure to make backups of those files beforehand to avoid corruption.

Let's suppose your program is called `prog`. To pause the program, run `kill -TSTP $(pidof prog)` while it's running. After you're done, resume it with `kill -CONT $(pidof prog)`.

Since you already know the location (and possibly the name of the temporary files), you can make this more precise by 'guarding' it with a while loop like so:

```
while [ ! -f /path/to/temp_file ]; do echo -ne 'Waiting for file...\r'; done ; kill -TSTP $(pidof prog)
```

The `while` loop will keep running until the temporary file exists and only then will `kill` be executed to send the `TSTP` signal.
Now, with the loop still running, run your program and copy the temporary file(s) if necessary, then resume the process to let it complete and terminate cleanly.